# How do I create this 3D effect box in XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm new in xaml world and I wish to create the effect of this box in xaml but I don't know how put the top and left border of the box in white color. Everyone can help me?

[image: A screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific effect, and as color gradients in Silverlight has no an "L" shape, I would make the left "White" with a regular linear gradient brush, and the top with an additional shape with a vertical linear gradient brush, located on top of the big rectangle.

Comment: Tks guy, I did using your tip and I created something that has helped me a lot. [link](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg806/scaled.php?server=806&filename=imagemxaml.png&res=medium)